# Have there been any studies of designs beyond the basic elevator in a rotating wheel space station?

Tags: space-station, artificial-gravity, feasibility, transport

In the 1977 [NASA publication](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19770014162.pdf), "Space Settlements, A Design Study," exploring the feasibility of the Stanford Torus

[image]

it says "Elevators could also be used to travel through the spokes to the far side of the colony," p. 33.

In a Worldbuilding SE question "[Elevator on rotating wheel space station](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/148566/elevator-on-rotating-wheel-space-station)" it is discussed how difficult creating a simple elevator in a rotating wheel space station would be. Has there been any in depth studies documented of an elevator for a rotating space station of any size?

Comment: The question is perfectly valid but why restricting it to NASA ?

Comment: Good point.  Too narrow thinking on my part.